# Probability that someone's salary is greater than $x$ but smaller than $y$

Tags: probability, self-study

I am getting stuck at the beginning of probabilities.
If there's 80% chance that someone's salary is more than $500$ Euros, and also $60\%$ chance that it's less than $1000$ Euros.
What is the probability that his salary will be between $500$ and $1000$ Euros?

Most things we've done so far are about sets, so I have no idea how to think about this.

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag and read its wiki. Have you studied cumulative distribution functions (CDFs)?

Comment: This indeed is a question about sets, because "salary more than 500" and "salary less than 1000" are events--sets with probabilities.  Drawing a diagram (like a Venn diagram) is always useful in such circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Assuming that salary is a continuous distribution, then we  have

$$P(500< X < 1000)=P(X < 1000) - P(X  \le 500)
$$

You should be able to figure out the individual terms on the right hand side from the description of the question.